# Sharepoint 2010, calling the external webservice without using workflow

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am very new to the SharePoint platform, and I need an insight as how can I achieve the following.

I need to call an external Webservice from Sharepoint(2010), without using workflow feature.
When the Webservice returns the data, I need to use one of value as a filter for an existing List.
e.g. Webservice returns user's department. I need to capture that department and use it a filer for an already existing List that displays information for all the departments. I need the List to display the information only for the department returned by the Webservice.

Comment: based on what i think your trying to do,  your only option will be a javascript ajax call to the webservice,  then you'll need to modify the list dynamically from there.

Comment: hmm, instead of javascript, can't this be done at the server level?

Comment: you would have to develop your own web part to do that,  but yes, it's doable.

Comment: You can try incorporating this using the SharePoint plus JQUERY Library:
http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/

If you can elaborate more on the exact workflow I can try to come up with some examples?

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to have your web service return the data as an external content type (BCS). That can then be used in an out of the box filter on a page. I do something similar with a client ID using the picker box from SP to select the item from the external source and then filter other web parts on the page.